# Charging issue and cranks but won't start

Tags: electrical, kia, charging, cranks-wont-run, sedona

I have a 2004 Kia Sedona, 3500 engine. I am having 2 issues:

1. I am having charging problem
2. Even trying to jump start it now it wont start, cranks over but won't start

I have jump started it a couple of days ago (Wednesday to be exact) and it started. Today I tried to jump start it after the van only sat in my driveway for 2 days. It cranks over, but won't start now. We checked the fuses and the fuel relay and they are working like they should.

Then there is the charging problem, the brake light and battery light were lit up on the dash, I'm assuming the alternator needs to be replaced, I am getting a little frustrated here, I don't have the money to send my vehicle to the garage. Can you please help me!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The brake and battery lights were on when the car was running or KOEO?